# Fortran/MPI Compilation Error IMPLICIT NONE statement cannot follow attribute declaration

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am in the process of learning MPI in fortran, and so I've been writing a bunch of small functions that do simple tasks in MPI to get a good handle on it. However, halfway through, i began getting this error when trying to compile

```
$ mpif90 example.f90 -o example.out
example.f90:108:17:

  108 |     implicit none
      |                 1
Error: IMPLICIT NONE statement at (1) cannot follow attribute declaration statement at (2)
```

which doesn't even show me where (2) is so I don't know whats causing the error. But when I commented out `implicit none`, it compiled fine and ran correctly. Any ideas as to what is happening here?

Code:

```
program send_vec
    include 'mpif.h'
    implicit none

    integer :: process_rank, cluster_size, ierror, message_item
    integer :: i
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: buffer_vector

    allocate(buffer_vector(1:10))

    call MPI_INIT(ierror)
    call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, cluster_size, ierror)
    call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, process_rank, ierror)

    if ( process_rank == 0 ) then
        do i = 1, 10
            buffer_vector(i) = i
        end do
        write (*,*) "sent:", buffer_vector
        call MPI_SEND(buffer_vector, 10, MPI_INT, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierror)
    else if (process_rank == 1) then
        call MPI_RECV(buffer_vector, 10, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierror)
        write (*,*) "recieved:", buffer_vector
    end if

    call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)
    
end program send_vec
```

Also this is mpif90 -v

```
mpifort for MPICH version 3.4.1
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-ZPT0kp/gcc-11-11.2.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-ZPT0kp/gcc-11-11.2.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.2.0 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`implicit none` must appear **before** `include 'mpif.h'`

That being said, this is very error prone, and you should at least use

```
program send_vec
use mpi
implicit none
...
```

(note the `implicit none` is **after** the `use mpi` line)

Ideally, you would

```
program send_vec
use mpi_f08
implicit none
...
```

but that will likely require you to modernize your code
(for example, a datatype has its own type (e.g. `Type(MPI_Datatype)` instead of `INTEGER`)

Comment: Thanks, that worked, all the examples I'd seen didn't use an implicit none, and they are fairly old. Do you have recommendations as to where to learn more modern fortran programming?

Comment: "Modern Fortran explained" is a good book. Note Fortran 2008 bindings uses a (very) small subset of the latest Fortran, so you can probably learn `use mpi_f08` from examples.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks.